How to add the sub campaign in civicrm
How to add the sub campaigns in civicrm.
eg:
BOOK (campaign)
white book (sub-campaign)
line book (sub-campaign)
Desk note book(sub-campaign)

I would recommend using the Campaign Manager extension. Among its features are:
Providing a campaign hierarchy

Creating the possibility for parent and child campaigns
Adapting the user interface for creating and viewing existing campaigns (e.g. a hierarchical „tree view“ and possibilities for filtering
Creating functions that simplify campaign management (such as copying complete campaigns including subsequent campaigns and adapting campaign dates)

Adding campaign fields and functions

Fields/function for adding categorized costs (such as postal fees, printing costs...)
Funtion to calculate the overall costs of of a single campaign and its child campaigns/actions


You can add them as a Custom field to the Campaign.
